# after deployment picture download from wcf service doesn't work how to find out what is wrong?

Tags: wcf, debugging, deployment, windows-server-2008

WCF service is used to retrieve data and pictures. WCF service work well on localhost, and on web-hosting of provider. But the same service  after deploying to server within local network  doesn't allow to retrieve pictures, however data comes successfully.

So:
WCF service data downloading: 
localhost (ok) 
web-hosting (winhost.com) (ok) 
remote server within local network (ok)

WCF service picture downloading (binary array of bytes): 
localhost (ok)
web-hosting (winhost.com) (ok)
remote server within local network (NO!!!!)

so it's strange because the same service perfectly works on web-hosting of winhost.com provider but refuses to give pictures on local server!

What could be problem?
I don't know should I do some configuration of server 2008?
At last I have to debug WCF service on remote server, but how to?

Comment: What error messages do you get? More details are needed

Comment: run wcftestclient <URL-to-svc-file>  from visual studio command prompt and see if you get an error message when using the service

Comment: I've just was able to see the logs of wcf service... but I hardly understand if there is errors

Comment: to James. Yes built in wcf client gives me errors as maxreceivedbytes there are limited. But my client application has no limits for maxreceivedbytes (very big)

Comment: Can your service return an exception? Also could it be timing out? why not write a basic console app to use the service and see what exceptions you get if you dont feel the wcftestclient is suitable. Without more details, nobody can really help

Comment: To James: Truly say I have more information than I could resolve it. Right now I just don't know how to get this information. That's why i'm asking how I can debug it. You advised me to make a console app, do you mean console app of client or wcf service? if client I can't see the difference between winforms and console. _ By the way. Thanks for good idea. I'll try to send back exception from WCF to client.  But still I thought I could debug wcf service from client side or at last at server side. _ I can send you by e-mail the log files.

Comment: A console client takes about 2 mins to write and you can set it up to be sure it outputs the exception being sent from the service. The winform application would be just as good if you are in a position to set up those checks. The point being, be sure the service throws exception info back to the client.

Comment: To James. You wont believe ))) problem was so small  but with your help I found out it. I've just forget to do it in the beginning. As I told you I have big value for maxReceivedMessages, So I was sure That problem wasn't with it. But I forgot that I simply use in my client side 3 service references  for the same code of wcf service but on different servers. I've just forgotten to put for the rest two of them the Max Value:

Comment: <binding name="BasicHttpBinding3" maxReceivedMessageSize="90000000" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding2"  maxReceivedMessageSize="90000000"  />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding1"  maxReceivedMessageSize="90000000"  />

Comment: To James: Thanks! How to give you +1?

Comment: Added an answer for you to accept. Glad you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
1)If you have several references for services don't forget to put for all of them the constraints; in configuration of app.config maxReceivedMessageSize. 
2)To debug service simply add some more details in reponse from wcf service

Answer (score 0):

A console client takes about 2 mins to write and you can set it up to be sure it outputs the exception being sent from the service. The winform application would be just as good if you are in a position to set up those checks. The point being, be sure the service throws exception info back to the client